# Passing an argument with one element as an array

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to pass an array to a ViewModel method:

```
self.helpMe = function ( myArray ) { 

    for (var i=1, ilen=myArray.length, i<ilen, i++) {
        //do something...
    } 
}
```

Sometimes my array will consist of only one item and the helpMe-function is called from another method:

```
self.saveMe = function (item) {

    self.helpMe( item.Topics );

    ...
}
```

where Topics is defined like this

```
self.Topics = ko.observableArray([]);
```

and instantiated as an query ui item with the "with" data-bind.

However say Topics only have one value [ "Sheeps" ] then myArray.length turns out to be 6 and not 1 as I want it to be. Where do I go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like your Array is in fact a string and the result is the length of the string "Sheeps"

Comment: @AsleG Take a better look at how youre setting `self.Topics` to `["Sheeps"]

Comment: @Kierchon Thanx. You are right. I had it mistaken for an array but in fact it was a comma separated string. Trying to fix it with  
"var helpArray = myArray.split(',');

Answer (score 1):

A neat knockout utility you could try instead..

```
self.helpMe = function ( myArray ) { 
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(myArray(), function () {
        //do something... This iterates through each element of the observableArray
    }
}
```

Please note, this doesn't answer your question...just posing an alternative that is far easier to use/read in my opinion.

Comment: Thanx. I´ll try to remember that. Hopefully my knockout-skills are getting better with time. Is there a listing of all these neat ko.utils anywhere?

Comment: `arrayForEach` will also be faster than an indexed loop on an implementation that supports ES5 (pretty much everything but IE6-8) since it will simply resolve to the built-in `forEach` method of arrays. jQuery also provides `$.each()` which works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I would change this line 
self.Topics = ko.observableArray([]);

to this line
self.Topics = ko.observableArray();

and the the following method

self.helpMe = function ( myArray ) {

```
for (var i=1, ilen=myArray.length, i<ilen, i++) {
    //do something...
}
```

}

to this

self.helpMe = function ( myArray ) {

```
for (var i=0, i < myArray.length - 1, i++) {
   self.Topics.push(myArray[i]);
}
```

}